# UWP Bluetooth​LEAdvertisement​Watcher periodically gets in Aborted state

Tags: bluetooth, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

My UWP C# application is by essence a headless one running in Win 10 IoT (current Insiders Preview build 10.0.17035.1000) on Raspberry Pi 3 SBC. Part of its functionality is to communicate with BLE devices. It is pretty stable but there are some UWP BLE communication problems I encounter. The most important one for now is that UWP Bluetooth​LEAdvertisement​Watcher, after started and stopped multiple times, periodically gets in Aborted state on a Start command. The solution I currently use to recover from a pending Aborted state is to restart the device using ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown() method. Can you, please, advise me if there is a more elegant solution to recover the Bluetooth​LEAdvertisement​Watcher to Started state.

Comment: Have you tested [this official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement/cs)? Does it can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Thank you Rita,I will try it immediately.

Comment: Actually I had this sample. It does not give much information. My application is a headless one running as a startup in Win 10 IoT. It starts the BLE Watcher and on a BLE advertisement received stops the BLE Watcher till processes the currently connected device communication. Then restarts the BLE Watcher. It does well this for some time (~ 1 hour, a couple of tenths of BLE Watcher stops/starts ) and then on one of the BLE Watcher stops/starts BLE Watcher gets in Aborted state. Please let me know if there is some way to make BLE Watcher more reliable and a better way to restart it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I just modified the sample you pointed to in order to simulate my application BLE Watcher stop/(re)start behavior. So far there were no BLE Watcher aborts reported. My application does the same. Still trying to find the reason for this problem.

Comment: Good news. If you find the problem out you can share it here.

Comment: In release mode after working for some time (~ 1 hour) the BLEWatcher still gets permanently into Aborted state. I have an ETW trace from a different thread which monitors the BLEWatcher in the device thread. This is the trace: "BleWatcherStatus is permanently Aborted- restarting the BLE device." I check the BLEWatcher status every 5 seconds and consider it not recoverable after trying to restart the BLEWatcher from Aborted state 3 times. Can I get more information about the possible reason for this behavior? The resort for now is to restart the device but it is not a solution for the problem.

Comment: If you can show your edits to [the official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement/cs) I can do some test.

Comment: Thank you Rita. I am conducting some verification and in case this problem reappears, I will share the code. It includes simple modification of the official sample for device detecting, connect, stop watcher, device disconnect, and start watcher.

Comment: Currently I don't see the BLEWatcher Abort pending problem in my application debug and release versions. But in both versions, after some time after started, on a BLEWatcher restart, the application hangs up. Nothing in particural is reported by Win 10 IoT which could help do identify the problem. Please let me know if this is a result of some Win 10 IoT update and how to fix this new problem.

Comment: For the new problem, you can post a new question with detailed information about your set up and reproduce steps.